# Publish to SQL Server 2014 from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I've recently moved from VS 2010 Professional to VS 2017 (Community Version).

I'm trying to publish a database, along with the rest of the web project, but I'm a little confused, and ultimately getting errors, which may be database compatibility issues.

As I'm using VS 2017, I'm using the built in LocalDB, but my target is SQL Server 2014 Web Edition.

I'm simply publishing using Web Deploy. For the database I want to update, I have added a remote connection string an checked 'use this connection at runtime' and 'update database'.

Here's the connection string:

```
Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=My2014Db;Integrated Security=False;User ID=DbUser;Password=1234567;Application Name=EntityFramework
```

I haven't set anything else in the project properties => publish SQL section.

When I publish, I get the following error:

```
The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql130DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
```

As this is all different and totally new to me, I'm not sure whether I've missed setting something up or it's just a compatibility issue with the server versions.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Using VS to publish an SSIS project to the Catalog I had to change my project properties and set target server version to 2014.  Maybe you are having the same type of issue?

Comment: It could well be Joe - as I said new version of VS, so fumbling around in the dark a bit. When you say, 'set target version to 2014', where can this be done? It's a webforms app, and I can't see any SQL target under properties.

Comment: For SSIS I just right click the project and select configuration settings.  Doing a quick search on  your message this might help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/672e612f-da93-4e50-a10e-7757af6b42e3/trying-to-copy-database-from-local-sql-server-2016-to-sql-server-2014-using-extractpublish?forum=sqlgetstarted